# Register first button pressed.

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi, raspbian, gpio

I'm making a simple quiz app on my raspberry under raspbian using c++.
I want it to store who pressed their button first. 
4 momentary buttons will be connected to the pi via GPIO, 
but for now i am testing by simply using my keyboard.

How should the function reading the buttons look like to avoid simultaneous presses?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please put some code in your question, showing us what you have done so far?

Answer (score 0):

If you record a timestamp with nanosecond resolution of when the "press" happened you are unlikely to get duplicates. And in the unlikely event that you do, just pick a random one of the dupes since that's just as right as whatever else you could do ;) See also http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono

Comment: Thanks a lot, i'll be looking into this. 
But the loop that's waiting for user input, how should it look like?
I cant use cin like getch() so im trying to figure out how to get the basic functionality to work.